# "your operating system listens on all public IPs" - what does that really mean and how does it work?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

This isn't a Python/Flask specific question, but I'll go ahead and use a Flask example. When I run this:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

my operating system is supposed to "listen on all public IPs" so that the web application will be accessible from all computers on the same network (I think).

So I tried to access my app from my smartphone (which is connected to the same LAN network through WiFi) by typing in the IP of my PC (where the app is running) and the default port but it doesn't work. My smartphone couldn't connect. I feel like I've misunderstood what is meant by "on the same network". Could someone please explain this to me?

My apologies if I have made any ridiculous/stupid assumptions about this, my understanding of it is obviously pretty shady/inconcise.

Comment: It listens on *all* IP addresses actually, whether public, private, local, whatever. I don't know what you mean by 'on the same network', or where you're getting all this dubious information.

Comment: from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/:
If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the run() method to look like this:
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

"Trust users on your network" was what made me think that.

Comment: So does this mean that, by running that command, I actually begin to host my web app on my computer that, if pointed at by a domain name, I could access with mydomain.com?

Comment: Th documentation reads like A grade rubbish to me. The answer to your last question is 'yes', firewalls and NAT permitting.

Comment: Ah now it all makes sense. Thanks!